# onClick funtion not working on checked radio button

Tags: jquery

I want to uncheck checked bootstrap radio button by clicking on it but its not working.

```
$("input[type=radio]:checked").click(function () {
  console.log("checked radio");
  $(this).attr("checked", false);
});
```

Comment: Hi use `$(this).prop("checked", false);` instead of `attr` see if that works .

Comment: Are you adding this click handler before or after the radio button is checked? If you're adding it while the radio button is still unchecked, then the event won't fire.

Comment: Any particular reason not to use a [switch](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#switches) instead?

Comment: You need to use `change` or `input` method instead of `click`.

Comment: tried but still don't work @RaeeshAlam

Comment: You can try @Swati answer as I try and its working fine.

Comment: Problem is its not getting inside the function.......event is not firing @RaeeshAlam

Comment: show your html code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try with `data-*` attribute for checking both value of `checked` and `data-status`. So condition is true or not. And one more method `removeAttr()` apply for `checked` attribute *remove* from radio input if condition true.

```js
$("input[type=radio]").on('click', function () {
    var getStatus = $(this).attr('data-status');
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && (getStatus=='1')) {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
        $(this).removeAttr("checked");
        $(this).attr('data-status','0');
    }else{
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
        $(this).attr('data-status', '1');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col col-md-8 py-2">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="wow" id="radiobutton" data-status="1" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="radiobutton">
            Default checked radio
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `checked` attribute exists, the radio button will be checked. it doesn't matter what value you give it. you can remove it via `$(this).removeAttr('checked')`.